# What are the options to develop a UI for a backend optimization code written using JuMP?

Tags: optimization, julia, julia-jump

I am right now working on a freight network optimization problem and want to develop a UI for a layman. The code is written using JuMP (Julia 0.6.2). I am trying to create a UI where the user can upload the data and do a bit of sensitivity analysis. What are my options in Julia?

Comment: You may want to read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: better to ask this kind of question on https://discourse.julialang.org/ :)

Answer (score 1):

While this question is not precise here is what I would do:

- publish the required back-end `JuMP` functionality as a RESTful API using `JuliaWebAPI.jl` and  `ZeroMQ.jl`
- develop the GUI frontend with a modern JavaScript stack such as Angular (independently of Julia)